# Adding a row upwards in R

Tags: r, sorting, smoothing

I'm using a recursive algorithm to generate samples and include them in a list. For that I was using rbind (since I dont know the final number of rows, so I cant just declare it and access trough `list[i, ]` to attribute the values).
The problem is I start sampling from the last value to the first, so my list is upside down.

Is there a way to use rbind to create a row upwards instead of downwards?

Example for ilustration:
Suppose you have `x1 = c(1, 2)` and `x2 = c(3, 4)`
if you do: `rbind(x1, x2)` you get:

```
1 2
3 4
```

But what I need is:

```
3 4
1 2
```

Remember that I cant just do `rbind(x2, x1)`, because I'm sampling backwards, so I don't have all values before binding.

Comment: I am probably missing something but what about `rev` at the end.  Then your list is in the "correct" order.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. I didn't know about this function. Thanks! But still, is there some way to do it directly?

Comment: Can you modify your example to show why `rbind(x2, x1)` doesn't work? Because it seems like at whatever point you `rbind`, you have the values to bind, so switching the order should work...

Comment: You would just switch the order of your `rbind`. As in `rbind(newobject, oldobject)`, but you said that did not work for some reason.

Comment: I cant see why you could not make that work with a recursive function, but it probably does not match the function you have.